# Upgrading Tex Live from 2015 to 2016 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, latex, texlive

Recently I upgraded Ubuntu from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS. Now I want to upgrade Tex Live from 2015 to 2016. I had a mess when I upgraded Tex Live from 2013 to 2015. I would highly appreciate if someone guide me how to do up-gradation from Tex Live from 2015 to 2016 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  Thanks

Looking for complete guide to upgrade Tex Live from 2015 to 2016 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: I strongly recommend to install latest from scratch. Otherwise, at some random point you will get a random error with a particular package which debugging will consume more time than the full installation. If you consider this, then [this answer in SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/77895) is the best guide ever on how to install Tex. Although it is for Ubuntu 14.04, I see no reason why it should not work in 16.04. I will not copy that answer here, because it just creates more entropy.

Comment: Don't forget to assign the bounty to the answer that solved your question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are happy to upgrade your *system* version of TeX Live you can install the very latest from a PPA. Add the PPA and install TeX Live from a Terminal as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive-2016
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

This installed with no issues on my own Xenial system:

```
andrew@athens:~$ tex --version
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.2
Copyright 2016 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
andrew@athens:~$
```

And hopefully will install with no issues on *your* system as well :)

**References:**

- [PPA TeX Live 2016: Backport of TeX Live 2016 packages for LTS releases](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive-2016)

Comment: Is it safe to remove older PPA after performing upgrade?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the latest TeXLive, follow the instructions at https://www.tug.org/texlive/

There is no problem with doing this, as it will not interfere at all with your system. You can install TeXLive in any directory you want (even in your home directory), so it is totally independent of Apt. This means also that it is possible to keep the Ubuntu TeXLive packages installed, if you have some other packages which depend on them.

Comment: Thanks @fkraiem for your answer. Would highly appreciate if you answer the question instead of providing a link. Thanks