# Installing TexLive 2016 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, texlive

What is the reason that by using `sudo apt install texlive-full` I only get TexLive version.2015, even though the newer versions such as 2016 and 2017 are out?

I am actually trying to install Texlive 2016.

Comment: And https://askubuntu.com/questions/794671/upgrading-tex-live-from-2015-to-2016-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/809779#809779

Comment: Ubuntu LTS is essentially a snapshot in time, with bugfixes applied.  The Java programmers learned this the hard way with Java 8 not being backported to 14.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately Ubuntu 16.04 only ships the [older version of TexLive](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/texlive). However for Ubuntu 16.04 you can install TexLive *2016* by adding the following PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive-2016
sudo apt-get update
```

and then installing TexLive as usual. Bear in mind that the same gentleman has separate PPAs with TexLive 2015 and 2017 also available for Ubuntu 16.04...